# Use the sum() on a result set returned by a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query returns the two lowests grades *{9,10}*

```
select TOP 2 grades.grade 
from grades
where grades.studentno = 1 
order by grade ASC
```

And I want to sum the result of grades with the `sum()` function and set the result of the `sum()` function to the variable `@sumLowerGrades`

I have attempted with this query

```
set @sumLowerGrades = sum(select TOP 2 grades.grade from grades
        where grades.studentno = 1 order by grade ASC)
```

But it fails with the following message:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
select @sumLowerGrades = sum(grade)
from (select TOP 2 grades.grade 
      from grades
      where grades.studentno = 1 
      order by grade ASC
     ) g;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but I have some questions
**1)** Why does `select` works instead of `set` on the first line?
**2)**  What is and does ´g;´ do at the end?

Comment: @Muddz Just wrap the query in () then `SET` will works for you, but `SELECT` do the same here. `g` is an alias for the subquery.

Comment: @Sami okay thanks. Another question then. Why is the alias `g` necessary then?

Comment: @Muddz It can be g or gg or whatever. Gordon just write `g` because the table name was `Grades`

Comment: @Sami
Yes I understand but why is aliasing necessary here. Thats is what I dont get

Comment: It's the Syntax, take it as a rule a `FROM` clause needs table names.

Answer (score 0):

Also can do as the following:

```
SET @sumLowerGrades = (SELECT sum(grade)
from (select TOP 2 grades.grade 
      from grades
      where grades.studentno = 1 
      order by grade ASC
     ) g);
```

A `FROM` clause requires table name/Names, so when you see

```
from (select TOP 2 grades.grade 
      from grades
      where grades.studentno = 1 
      order by grade ASC
     ) g
```

Is making this query/dataset as table and here `g` is the name given to the subquery within the brackets.